# Schedule a paused job with Quartz

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I'd like to created a job in paused state.

```
Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.newTrigger()
/* Trigger config */
.build();

JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(JobLauncher.class)
/* Job Config */
.build()

//schedule job (might be in paused state...)
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

I can't find any methods in TriggerBuilder nor JobBuilder to set the trigger or job to be in paused state when scheduled.

I'm forced to use something like this just after scheduling

```
//pause just scheduled job...
scheduler.pauseJob(jobKey);
```

Is there any way to do so ?

Comment: Sorry question is not clear..Do you mean, you want to create a job and pause it immediately ?

Comment: Exactly, this is what I mean.
Create the Job as a paused Job.

Comment: I use quartz for a daily sync job, to avoid it running immediately upon server boot-up, I simply used a `if(firstRun)` boolean. Which essentially pauses/skips the job until the next scheduled run. Will that work for your situation?

Comment: i don't think so. I already have something to avoid first run.